# How add BinarySecurityToken in the call to webservice with .pfx certificate? C#

Tags: c#, web-services, timestamp, ws-security, soapheader

I'm working with c#.net Framework 4.5, visual studio 2012...I´m trying to add a web reference in my solution. This web reference is protected with a two leveled security wall. The provider of the WS brought me two certificates: one is .p12 and the other is **.pfx**. The first one is used to go throw de proxy, and the second one is to sign the calls to the methods included in the WS. Up to now, I succeeded on adding the Web reference, but when I´m trying to call their methods, I can´t pass the second wall of security, 'cause I don´t know how to define in my code the "signing" of the calls to the methods. I' ve already installe the certificate in my local PC, but I´m stucked here...don´t know how to sign the calls to the methods of the WS from the code.

**Edit: 06/01/2015**
I found the solution in this post:
[How to consume third party https wsdl web service in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21861230/how-to-consume-third-party-https-wsdl-web-service-in-c-sharp)

My problem now is to remove the timestamp of the header when I call the service (it's a web reference and not a service reference, so I can not use customBinding)

Answer (score 0):

The information that I needed was here:

Add the securityToken
[How to consume third party https wsdl web service in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21861230/how-to-consume-third-party-https-wsdl-web-service-in-c-sharp)

Remove Timestamp and anothers tags
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dhrubach/archive/2008/06/16/modifying-the-security-header-generated-by-wse-runtime.aspx