# C# soap client error "The request failed with HTTP status 404: Not Found."

Tags: c#, http, soap

I have been provided soap project(.XML) and keystore(jks) by third party which I am trying to consume in my C# application.

The services are working fine in SOAPUI but getting error when sending request from C#(The request failed with HTTP status 404: Not Found.)

Steps I followed so far

1) Exported WSDL from SOAPUI, added web reference in C# application
2) changed the endpoint in the config(same as that of SOAPUI).
3) Converted jks to pfx(tried with p12 too) and added to request's client certificate

Apart from this I also followed the steps mentioned in the below link, but still no luck.

[How to consume third party https wsdl web service in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21861230/how-to-consume-third-party-https-wsdl-web-service-in-c-sharp)

Can somebody point me to the right direction. Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that the address is still valid? Error 404 means that the page/service was not found. It can be a simple typo *(do not forget case sensitive check)*, or simply it was once used, but now it is no longer used and was replaced, or stopped *(out of service)*. But since there are no details, nobody can help you.

Comment: Yes the endpoint is valid as I am using the same in SOAP UI and it's working completely fine